# How to increase basis set while running cluster calculations

Tags: computational-chemistry, polymers, density-functional-theory, basis-set

I am running (opt+freq)DFT calculations using 6-311G(d) basis set on polymers with different number of monomer units. Upto 2 monomer units optimization is converged but for 4 units max displacement criteria is not converged. Which starting point do I need to consider while increasing the basis set?

Comment: What do you mean by increasing the basis set? Do you mean using a larger basis set? For the 4 unit polymer does the optimization run out of steps?

Comment: Sometimes for large molecules, it can take a long time for optimizations to converge  because the torsions are low-energy and take many steps to settle.